# Sharpie and GVRSDK binding for Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, google-cardboard, xamarin-binding

I want to bind the GVRSDK.ios (GOOGLE Cardboard SDK) library into my Xamarin project, but I am running into some issues.

When I try to create the binding using Sharpie I only get "GoogleToolboxForMac" and "GTMSessionFetcher" to bind; 2 sets of attributes and struct files are created.

The library I want is GVRSDK, but this library is not being bound. Can someone guide me in the right direction? this is my first binding for ios.

commands used:

```
sharpie pod init ios GVRSDK
sharpie pod bind
```

I read the documentation on the site, but I still can't get my head around it. must of the samples out there use simple library with not dependencies which do not apply to this.